# "Бежалось", "бежались" -- морфология слова

Tags: глаголы

Существует ли такая форма глагола -- *бежались*? Если да, то есть ли у вас примеры употребления? Например, "первые километры марафона *бежались* гораздо легче". Грамотно это или нет?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

В русском языке некоторые глаголы  могут иметь **два значения**: личное и безличное, о чем всегда указывается в словаре. Например, **для глагола «петься»** указаны два значения, при этом во втором значении глагол употребляется **как в личной, так и безличной форме**:

**ПЕТЬСЯ,** поётся; нсв. 1. кому. безл. О желании, настроении петь. Вдвоём как-то хорошо поётся. Сегодня что-то не поётся. 2.Исполняться голосом (о музыкальном произведении). Песня поётся на два голоса. Романс хорошо поётся под гитару. В песне пелось о несчастной любви.

В словаре  Ефремовой указано **только безличное значение** глагола "бежаться" как возможность или желание бежать. Поэтому правомерна такая постановка вопроса: **может ли  глагол  «бежаться» иметь (или приобретать хотя бы в разговорной речи) личное значение?** Попробуем на него ответить.

По значению к «бежаться» ближе всего глаголы **«спаться, сидеться, лежаться».**  Эти глаголы относятся к нейтральной (а не к разговорной) лексике и развить другие (личные) значения не пытаются (к примеру, мы не говорим «ночь спалась хорошо»).

Рассмотрим два примера: **Первые километры марафона бежались гораздо легче. По рыхлому снегу даже крохотная дистанция бежалась неплохо.** Разницы между ними никакой (подлежащее – это первые километры и дистанция), а проблема одна и та же. **Понятно желание использовать личную форму даже при ее отсутствии в словарях -  она позволяет сделать текст более кратким и выразительным.** 
Поэтому почему бы не сделать первые шаги  в освоении **личного** глагола «бежаться», при этом ясно осознавая, в чем заключена новизна такой формы.

Comment: *В русском языке некоторые глаголы могут иметь два значения* - В огороде бузина, в Киеве дядька. Вопрос не в личности-безличности, а в том, допустимо ли километры делать субъектом или объектом этого глагола. Если что тут и существенно, то переходность, но она "закрыта" возвратностью формы.

Comment: У Вас серьезные проблемы с грамматикой личных и безличных глаголов.  Вот пример: Что-то сегодня не поется (безличн. глагол). Допустимо ли глагол "петься" делать субъектом  действия? Допустимо: песня поется. Только в этом случае это уже не безличный,  а личный глагол в форме пассивного залога (сравнить:  дом (что делает?) строится). Безличный глагол не может соотноситься с подлежащим. Поэтому вопрос все-таки в личности/безличности, как все и пытаются Вам втолковать, а не в субъектах/объектах. Кстати, "первые километры" - это подлежащее, какое  обстоятельство! Согласование во мн.ч. с подлежащим.

Comment: Sergey, Вы вас проблемы с пониманием написанного. А заодно - и  чувством собственного величия. Давайте так. Если хотите что-то мне возразить, начинаете с конкретной мысли, которую Вы не поняли. Вот как я делаю. Я не возражаю против вашего понимания безличности, я против того, что это имеет какое-то отношение к вопросу. Вот давайте на этом и остановимся. А мои проблемы безотносительно к теме - не вам обсуждать.

Comment: *"первые километры" - это подлежащее, какое обстоятельство!* - Это обстоятельство, потому, что отвечает на вопрос "когда?". Можно заменить без ущерба для грамматики на "в течение первых километров", "во время пробега первых километров". Вы со своим примитивистским подходом совершенно не чувствуете смысла.

Comment: Я легко бежал первые километры - первые километры мне легко бежалось. Ну какое еще тут подлежащее? А в конструкции с "бежались" его приходится делать подлежащим (ну - в школьном понимании оного) .  Я и высказывался *против того, чтобы делать из обстоятельства подлежащее*. Вы это пропустили.

Comment: Давайте так. Если Вы не поняли чей-либо ответ, не надо его комментировать и минусовать, так как это МЕШАЕТ РАБОТЕ ФОРУМА. И пожалуйста, без ярлыков, Вы должны уважать оппонента, берите с меня пример.  Мой вариант: первые километры (дистанции) бежались... У Вас: "во время пробега первых километров", а дальше что? Сказуемое согласуется с  с обстоятельством?

Comment: Нет, ваш вариант мне не подходит, ибо я критикую всегда адресно и всегда говорю, что именно мне не понравилось, с указанием места. А Вы начинаете читать лекции по вопросам в которых разбираетесь явно не лучше того, кому вздумали просвещать. А в отношении уважения, так я считаю ваши манеры проявлением *неуважения* и зазнайства. Не могу их принять никак.  Мне важно увидеть, что Вы р\отвечаете мне на мои мысли, а не на собственные домыслы, поэтому я и прошу сначала формулировать тезис который вы оспариваете. Объяснять-то что-либо без просьбы считаю некорректным.

Comment: *Мой вариант: первые километры (дистанции) бежались... У Вас: "во время пробега первых километров", а дальше что? Сказуемое согласуется с с обстоятельством?* - где у меня сказуемое согласуется с обстоятельством? Еще раз повторяю,  вы спорите со своими домыслами. Фактически предъявляя мне те же претензии, что и я вам.

Comment: Могу повторить, хотя уже надоело. 1) Во фразах *Я легко бежал первые километры - первые километры мне легко бежалось.* - первые километры ***обстоятельство***, отвечает на вопрос "когда?" или "где?". 2) Во фразе *"Первые километры (мне) легко бежались* - обстоятельство (не дополнение, что можно было бы принять!) вынужденно становится подлежащим, что нарушает логику фразы. Всё. Где тут проблемы с грамматикой? И это вопрос переходности, а не безличности.

Comment: А я Вас повторно прошу не употреблять бранных слов,  научитесь вести себя прилично. Здесь должны обсуждаться лингвистические вопросы,  а Вы устраиваете кухонные разборки.

Comment: Я не употребляю бранных слов, сколько бы Вы меня о том не просили.  Говорите по существу, если есть что сказать.

Comment: *И это вопрос переходности, а не безличности*. Сравните: *Первые часы мне легко спалось*. Глагол безличный, но не это мешает сказать *"первые часы мне спались"*. А то, что "спать кого" нельзя. А "бежать дистанцию" - можно, как минимум в разговоре.

Comment: "И это вопрос переходности, а не безличности" - спорно. Понятно, что безличность здесь не главное. Но вот вопрос о том, чем является "финишные километры" допускает как минимум два ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли. "Первые километры бежалось гораздо легче". Это безличный глагол.

Comment: При чем тут безличность? "Эти работы мне удались", "По дороге встретились знакомые" - и проч.

Comment: behemothus, понятно, что вам сейчас хочется цепляться к каждому моему слову. Эту черту вашего характера я раскусил: "если уж я решил, что он дурак – он дурак во всем".
Но здесь получается немного смешно: вы в своём ответе фактически со мной соглашаетесь ("поэтому вариант с личной формой кажется мне грамматически неверным", " вынужден вариант с личной формой забраковать"), но возможности пнуть не упускаете. Продолжайте, продолжайте, я люблю-с. ))


P.S. Минус-то поставить не забудьте. Я знаю, вы любите ))

Comment: "При чем тут безличность" - странный комментарий, тут как раз всё дело в безличности. Если глагол безличный, то он не может иметь форму "бежались", нет у безличных глаголов  в прошедшем времени такой формы, есть только "бежалось". И при чем тут глаголы "удаться и встретиться"? "Встретиться" - это личный глагол,  изменяется по лицам и числам во всех значениях, а "удаться" может быть личным и безличным: намерения не удались (личн.) и мне удалось достать билет (безличн.).

Comment: *"При чем тут безличность" - странный комментарий* - ваш ответ еще более странный.

Comment: *behemothus, понятно, что вам сейчас хочется цепляться к каждому моему слову* - нет. Мне Вы глубоко безразличны. Единственный из активных участников, кого я тут для себя как-то выделяю, это Людмила, но в исключительно положительном смысле. Все остальные моим личным отношением не пользуются.

Comment: Очень хорошо. Лишь бы вам грамматика не была "глубоко безразличной". Когда вы высказываете мнение, в корне расходящиеся с общепринятым (не запрещено!), то хотя бы мелким шрифтом отмечайте: это, мол, чисто мое мнение. Это насчёт "первых километров" как обстоятельства и их невозможности быть подлежащим ("ну какое это подлежащее!")

Answer (score -2):

Лопатин дает его без помет, но в других словарях его нет.
Разумно, думаю, считать, что "бежалось" - глагол существующий, но разговорный, примерно как "спаться".

Но тут вот какая штука. В форме "мне хорощо бежалось первые километры" (="Мне хорошо спалось")  "первые километры" выполняет роль обстоятельства, поэтому переделка его в форму "Мне хорошо бежались первые километры" весьма сомнительна, ибо ни в качестве подлежащего, ни в качестве прямого дополнения километры выступать не могут.
Поэтому вариант с личной формой кажется мне грамматически неверным. Если бы что-то могло "бежаться" не в обстоятельственном значении, я бы принял такой вариант. "Как песни пелись". Для "бежалось" я такого примера не подберу. Поэтому вынужден вариант с личной формой забраковать. Но только поэтому.
(+)
Я нашел нечто.
*По рыхлому снегу даже крохотная дистанция бежалась неплохо*.

Инстаграм, понятно, не тот источник, который можно считать норимирующим, но это имеено тот пример, который я готов признать допустимо-разговорыным. Здесь "дистанция" в роли подлежащего вполне смотрится.

Comment: спасибо всем за интересные ответы, но к единому мнению так все таки мы и не пришли? "Финишные километры по набережной бежались хорошо и легко, но желания выжать из себя всё до последней капли не возникало"

Comment: Как же не пришли? Литературной норме не соответствует, но см. ответ Sergey. Я бы добавил, что повторять в тексте эту форму несколько раз (даже два) я бы не стал.

Comment: ок) все было прочитано и перечитано еще раз, более внимательно, спасибо

Comment: Vera Ioannidi, к единому мнению не пришли, это факт. Это Niemand сам с собой пришел к единому мнению)))  Что могу сказать. Будь я редактором, фразу такую я бы в печать пропустить не рискнул. Но если автор настаивает, то возразить не смогу. Мне не нравится именно использование в роли подлежащего того, что по смыслу является обстоятельством. Ведь "последние километры" - здесь это не "что?", это "когда?" или "где?". А в остальном я вполне допускаю использование "бежались". Проблема - в переходности. Можно "бежать дистанцию" (в профессиональном сленге - точно).

Comment: Значит и в возвратной форме дистанция может "бежаться". А вот "километры" - не то. Километры не бегают, их разве что пробегают. Вот и вся моя мысль. Можно соглашаться или не соглашаться, но она именно такая.

Comment: Исправляем предложение: Финишные километры по набережной  спортсмены бежали хорошо и легко, но желания выжать из себя всё до последней капли  у них не возникало. Теперь читаем, что получилось. Во-первых, текст увеличился в объеме. Во-вторых,  в первом предложении автор наблюдает за спортсменами со стороны, а во втором уже знает, что они чувствуют. Нет, не годится. А как бы вы написали, не используя глагол "бежаться" в личной форме, но так, чтобы было кратко, выразительно, эмоционально?

Comment: Sergey, исправить подобным образом любой дурак может. Только из емкой и сочной фразы у вас получился продукт косноязычного бюрократа.

Comment: *А как бы вы написали, не используя глагол "бежаться" в личной форме, но так, чтобы было кратко, выразительно, эмоционально?* - это аргумент? © "Если нельзя, но очень хочется, то можно"?

Comment: Вы меня удивляете! Мне как раз и хотелось, чтобы из "емкой и сочной фразы получился продукт косноязычного бюрократа".  Но где же Ваш вариант емкой и красочной речи, покажите нам мастер-класс.

Comment: *Вы меня удивляете!* - ну это-то неудивительно. Вам предстоит еще много раз удивиться, если начнете думать над прочитанным, а не с видом знатока отвечать банальностями.

Comment: *Но где же Ваш вариант емкой и красочной речи, покажите нам мастер-класс.* - Что за ерунда, где я Вам обещал показывать-мастер класс? Вы меня явно с собой перепутали. И какое это имеет отношение к вопросу? Тезис назовите, чего ради мне сейчас искать свой вариант, если вопрос правки вообще никем (кроме Вас) не обсуждается?